# Launch SignalR from .NET Core 2.1 Web API project inside IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-core-signalr

I built with Visual Studio 2017 a new project: "ASP.NET Core Web Application", then "API" project (ASP.NET Core 2.1) and I added `SignalR` as shown in this guide: https://code-maze.com/netcore-signalr-angular/

I'm able to launch the project with console by commenting the IIS Express profile in `launchSettings.json` as follows:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false, 
    "anonymousAuthentication": true, 
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:64155",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    /*"IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": false,
      "launchUrl": "api/values",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },*/
    "WebApplication2": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": false,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5001",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In that case my (Ionic 4) client succeeds to connect:

```
[2020-08-22T10:41:21.539Z] Information: WebSocket connected to ws://localhost:5001/testHub?id=iUNCgO8mFOt7MjdQB-Cn_Q.
```

However, if i start debugging in IIS Express (without commeting the IISExpress profile, i tried also to use different values for `launchBrowser` property), the API is working but it seems that SignalR does not get launched.

**EDIT:**

This is the error shown on console when i launch Visual Studio project in IIS Express, the error is the same that i would get if i launch the client without starting the debug on Visual Studio 2017 so, since it is working when the project is launched as a console app, i thought I was missing some configuration.

[image: Client error]

What is the correct configuration to start `SignalR` keeping the IIS Express default launch method? I would like at the end to be able to publish solution and deploy it to IIS. Starting site from IIS is enough to setup `SignalR` configuration?

Also, is it possible at the end to log SignalR messages (handling events) in a given log file?

This is my `Startup.cs` file:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using WebApplication2.SignalR;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

            services.AddSignalR();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseCors(options => options.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials());

            app.UseMvc();

            app.UseSignalR(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapHub<TestHub>("/testHub");
                
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And this is `Program.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
}
```

Is it possible to launch `SignalR` from `Main` method?

Comment: What does it mean that "signalr doesn't get started"? What happens when you attempt to connect? An error, if so which?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, i updated question with client error

Comment: @Ansharja Looks like your client application is running on url which is different than the API url. Check the solution provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54762611/signalr-failed-to-start-the-connection

Comment: @MohsinMehmood: Thank you, that did not work but I found another answer with solution, i was calling the wrong URL once server was running on IIS profile, check my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted solution as an edit but maybe it was not easy to see.

I found the correct answer to my issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57654495/6449672: after moving to IIS Express profile I had to change the url called by client from `http://localhost:5001/testHub` to `http://localhost:64155/testHub`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding cors to your startup.cs file?